# Handling missing values when calculating matching distances with the 'proxy' package

Tags: r, matrix, proxy, na, missing-data

I have a function that calculates simple matching distances in a matrix with ordinal data:

```
require(proxy)
m <- test
f <- function(x,y) sum(x == y) / NROW(x)
matches <- as.matrix(dist(m, f, upper=TRUE))
```

The problem is that this function won't work when there are missing values, such as in the following matrix.

```
test <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, NA), X2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 
3, 6), X3 = c(3, 4, NA, 5, 3, 2), X4 = c(2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 8), X5 = c(1, 
3, 2, 4, 6, 4)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The resulting distance matrix for this will be:

```
> matches
    1   2  3  4   5  6
1 0.0 0.0 NA  0 0.2 NA
2 0.0 0.0 NA  0 0.4 NA
3  NA  NA  0 NA  NA NA
4 0.0 0.0 NA  0 0.0 NA
5 0.2 0.4 NA  0 0.0 NA
6  NA  NA NA NA  NA  0
```

How can I adapt this function to calculate matching distances even when there are missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
f <- function(x,y) mean(x == y, na.rm = TRUE)

as.matrix(dist(m, f, upper=TRUE))
#     1   2 3    4   5    6
# 1 0.0 0.0 0 0.00 0.2 0.00
# 2 0.0 0.0 0 0.00 0.4 0.00
# 3 0.0 0.0 0 0.00 0.0 0.00
# 4 0.0 0.0 0 0.00 0.0 0.25
# 5 0.2 0.4 0 0.00 0.0 0.00
# 6 0.0 0.0 0 0.25 0.0 0.00
```

Also be aware that `numeric` vectors are subject to floating point errors so `==` will not always return what you think. This won't be a problem if you store your data as a matrix of `integer`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it seems as though you want to treat NAs not as a missing value, but another 'category'. In that case, you could treat the columns in your data.frame as characters and paste an arbitrary character in front of everything (to have NAs act like they exist). For example,

```
for (i in 1:length(test)) test[[i]] <- paste0("*", as.character(test[[i]]))
```

Then

```
require(proxy)
m <- test
f <- function(x,y) sum(x == y) / length(x)
matches <- as.matrix(dist(m, f, upper=TRUE))

 1    2   3  4  5   6
1 0.0 0.0 0 0.0 0.2 0.0
2 0.0 0.0 0 0.0 0.4 0.0
3 0.0 0.0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4 0.0 0.0 0 0.0 0.0 0.2
5 0.2 0.4 0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6 0.0 0.0 0 0.2 0.0 0.0
```

Note that I changed `NROW(x)` to `length(x)`